# Changing background via class name and JS array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get this to work where it will: Remove the current class (current array value) and add in the next class (next array value).

Essentially, this is it.

```
    var myFunction= function (step) {
        if (lastEntered === step) {
            triggerEvent(step, "impress:stepleave");
            lastEntered = null;
 // Adding in an array of gradients 
var i;
var bg = new Aray();
bg[0] = "gradient-0";       
bg[1] = "gradient-1";       
bg[2] = "gradient-2";               
bg[3] = "gradient-3";       
bg[4] = "gradient-4";       
bg[5] = "gradient-5";                   
bg[6] = "gradient-6";       
bg[7] = "gradient-7";       
bg[8] = "gradient-8";                   

            for (i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
            {
            body.classList.add(bg[i]);
            }
        }
    };
```

*Where **body.classList.add("gradient-1");** was put, it changed the color once without disrupting the rest of the script.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all a better practice for defining an array would be:

```
var bg = ["gradient-0", "gradient-1", "gradient-0", you get the idea...];
```

What exactly are you trying to do?
Your code adds all 9 classNames to body each time yourFunction is been invoked.
You can use the remove method of classList to remove a className.
Does it depend on the value of step what className body should have?
You could do something like this:

```
body.className = bg[step];
```

This will remove all classNames of body and give it the className bg[step];

Or if body has classNames different than the ones in bg then you could do this:

```
var i = 0, len = bg.length;
for ( ; i<len; i++) {
  if (i === step) { body.classList.add(bg[i]);
  } else {
    if (body.classList.contains(bg[i]) { body.classList.remove(bg[i]); }
  }
}
```

Hopefully I was helpful but I'm not really sure what step is and what your function is supposed to do ;}

Comment: What I'm trying to do is add bg styling to this neat presentation script. http://bartaz.github.com/impress.js/#/bored

Comment: Do you want to change the background style of body at every step? When body has all 9 classes it will get the styling listed last in the css. If you want to change the background depending on the step then you need to remove all classes besides the one corresponding to step. I'm not sure what the for-loop is for, since it adds all 9 classes to body everytime the function's been invoked